# How to reload table view inside a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following function:

```
func createTableViewCard() {
     let myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))

     let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: screenSize.width-20, height: screenSize.height-20))

     newView.addSubview(myTableView)

     view.addSubview(newView)
}
```

Now, inside my `viewDidLoad()`, I would like to "reloadData" for this tableView that I just added to the main view.

How can I do that?

Comment: Make `myTableView` a property of your class

Answer (score 2):

Make `myTableView` a property of your class and reload it on the main thread:

```
func refreshUI() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.Call createTableViewCard function when you wanna add tableView into UIView.Call refreshUI function when you need to reload

```
   class YOUR_CLASS {     
      let myTableView = UITableView()
      ovverride func viewDidLoad(){
         self.createTableViewCard() // call this method when you want add tableView
      }
      func createTableViewCard() {
         self.myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))
         let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: screenSize.width-20, height: screenSize.height-20))
         newView.addSubview(myTableView)
         view.addSubview(newView)
      }
      func refreshUI() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare your table view instance globally

```
var myTableView :UITableView!
```

until and unless you don't assign the delegate and datasource reload function does not work

```
func createTableViewCard() {
     myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))

     let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: screenSize.width-20, height: screenSize.height-20))

     newView.addSubview(myTableView)
     myTableView.delegate = self
     myTableView.datasource = self
     view.addSubview(newView)
}
```

later your can reload data easily

```
myTableView.reloadData()
```